# How can I insert buttons with discord.py and discord.ext.commands?

Tags: python, button, discord, bots, interactive

Remember, this is NOT discord-py-slash-commands, just discord.py module. Also not reaction buttons. I want to create interaction buttons. Can anyone help? Please help!!

```
@bot.command()
async def buttons(ctx):
... # the button (interactive) goes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of discord.py. It will be available in v2.0, which is in beta testing.